# Is there a kendo component for a week-based activity planning interface?

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm looking for a Kendo component suitable for displaying a week-based activity planning interface. I need to be able to view a table with the following specs:

In the header for each column, the range of working days of a week in a month (e.g. 5/06 - 9/06, 12/06 - 16/06, etc.);
In the first column a list of users;
In the cells that cross users and periods, activities referring to users per period. It's also convenient to be able to use drag and drop for activities in different cells and a convenient way to switch months and/or years.
I attach, to give an idea, what I tried to do with the Kendo component called Scheduler which respects the requirements for users and activities, allows the use of drag and drop and it can navigate comfortably, but unfortunately the header date range is not available. Any advice?

img -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyIdO.png

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.3.1109/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.3.1109/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<script id="groupHeaderTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <strong style="color: #=color#">#=text#</strong>
</script>
<div id="scheduler"></div>
<script>
  let datavera = new Date("2013/6/6");
  let end = new Date("2013/6/13")
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
    date: new Date("2013/6/6"), 
    showWorkHours: true,
    footer: false,
    dataSource: [
      {
        id: 1,
        start: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00 AM"),
        end: new Date("2013/6/6 09:00 AM"),
        title: "Interview",
        isAllDay: true,
        attendees: 1
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        start: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00 AM"),
        end: new Date("2013/6/6 09:00 AM"),
        title: "Meeting",
        isAllDay: true,
        attendees:  3 
      }
    ],
    views: [{ type: "timelineWeek", majorTick: 1440, majorTimeHeaderTemplate: kendo.template("#=kendo.toString(datavera, 'D')# - #=kendo.toString(kendo.date.addDays(end, -1), 'D')#")}],
    resources: [ {
    field: "attendees",
    name: "Attendees",
    dataSource: [
        { text: "Alex", value: 1, room: 1, color: "blue" },
        { text: "Bob", value: 2, room: 1, color: "#6eb3fa" },
        { text: "Charlie", value: 3, room: 2, color: "red" },
        { text: "Andrea", value: 4, room: 1, color: "green" },
        { text: "Lucas", value: 5, room: 1, color: "orange" }
    ],
    title: "Attendees"
  }],
  group: {
      resources: ["Attendees"],
      orientation: "vertical"
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [dateHeaderTemplate](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler/configuration/views.dateheadertemplate) configuration to change the format in the header:

```
 views: [{ 
  type: "timelineWeek", 
  majorTick: 1440, 
  dateHeaderTemplate: kendo.template("<strong>#=kendo.toString(date, 'D')#</strong>"),
  majorTimeHeaderTemplate: " ",
  selectedDateFormat: "{0:dd-MM-yyyy} - {1:dd-MMM-yyyy}"
}],
```

The `selectedDateFormat` will change the format of the date in the ToolBar, next to the calendar icon, in case you need to change that as well.

[Example](https://dojo.telerik.com/iNeQALIV)

Comment: I can change the names, but how can i change a day in a period of 2 dates for each column? the result should be different for each column.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "change a day in a period of 2 dates for each column"? You can navigate to next/previous week, but the range will be of 7 consecutive days.

Comment: For each column i need weeks not days, something like this: (first column: 2/2/2014 - 8/2/2014) |(second column: 9/2/2014 - 15/2/2014) | (third column: 16/2/2014 - 22/2/2014) | etc.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, there is no such built-in view, you will need to create a [custom one](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/scheduling/scheduler/views#custom-views). The closest option I can think of is having a timelineMonth view with narrow columns, but there will still be a column for each day, for [example](https://dojo.telerik.com/amopevIm).

Comment: Thanks, i think it's a good compromise